# Change the LayoutKind from Fixed to Sequencial for CppSharp C# bindings

Tags: c#, mono, interop, marshalling

I am generating C# bindings for a C library using [CppSharp](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp/blob/master/docs/GeneratingBindings.md),
but the generated bindings generate explicit structure layouts (LayoutKind.Explicit).

This makes the code fixed to a 32bit or 64bit configuration since,
Is there any way of changing the generated code to use a Sequencial layout instead?

Comment: It is an open source project with a MIT license.  So just fork it, make it work the way you want it and submit a pull request.  The open source way.  Don't forget that C code may contain unions, they always require LayoutKind.Explicit.  Presumably the detail that the author did not want to deal with.

Comment: @HansPassant: seem this is the way to go since it's not really implemented. I wanted to first check that I am not reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CppSharp author here! You can enable sequential layouts with the GenerateSequentialLayout option.